# Performance issue with SQL server due to sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

Need some help to solve this error:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
>   produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.

SQL query: (I am just putting one of the query. I got 9 such queries running)

```
var query1 = from article in _db.Articles
             from scl in article.Scls
             where article.publishDate < DateTime.Now
                && article.removalDate > DateTime.Now
                && article.finished == true
                && article.flagged== true
                && listOfScl.Contains(scl.id)
             select article;

var query2 = from article in _db.Articles
             from com in article.Coms
             where article.publishDate < DateTime.Now
                && article.removalDate > DateTime.Now
                && article.finished == true
                && article.flagged== true
                && listOfCom.Contains(com.id)
             select article;

query = (query1.Union(query2)).Distinct();
```

Don't know what is wrong with query its working fine but giving some performance issue on SQL Server.

I need some help to avoid such error and re-write this SQL query without using `UNION`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this .NET `LINQ to SQL`? Definitely not normal SQL syntax. It appears your main problem is using an ORM tool but not knowing you are using an ORM tool...

Comment: Yes, using .NET LINQ to SQL

Comment: In order for us to help with SQL performance, you'll need to extract the query that is actually running on the DB so we can see what is going on.

Comment: @N West - Its very long query. do you want me to put it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also note that by default LINQ does UNION, which will eliminate duplicates, **therefore there is no need for Distinct, which will likely improve performance.**

"re-write this SQL query without using UNION.".  How is this?

```
var query1 = from article in _db.Articles
             from scl in article.Scls
             where article.publishDate < DateTime.Now
                && article.removalDate > DateTime.Now
                && article.finished == true
                && article.flagged== true
                && ( 
                     listOfScl.Contains(scl.id)
                     || listOfCom.Contains(com.id) 
                   )
             select article;
```

You could try the performance of this, so that you don't need a distinct.  It will involve a subquery though, so it's hard to say what will perform better without testing:

```
var query1 = _db.Articles.Where(article => article.publishDate < DateTime.Now
                && article.removalDate > DateTime.Now
                && article.finished == true
                && article.flagged== true
                && ( article.Scls.Any(s=> listOfScl.Contains(s.id))
                     || article.Coms.Any(c=> listOfCom.Contains(c.id))
                   )
                );
```

Comment: I tried this query and its not eliminating duplicates articles. Getting some of the articles 2 times.

Comment: Sounds like multiple Scsls can reference an Article, so you would still need Distinct in that case.  Sorry, I had assumed you were doing distinct due to the use of Union and didn't think about the one-to-many relationships.

Comment: @user2263417 Added one other idea, I'm not sure it will compile/work, but you can give it a try.

Comment: @user2263417 Let me know if it does work, I'd be curious.  Sorry I'm not where I can setup a test on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Aaron...I will try out this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @Aanon - Looks like its working better. Didnt hear anything from DBA about blocking process or performance issue. I will update you once i hear anything from them...Thanks